# Can't iterate through a list and click on checkbox selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

```
<div>
  <ul class="nav border rounded p-2">
    <li class="nav-item col-12">
      <input type="checkbox" /> <span>Paediatrics</span>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item col-12">
      <input type="checkbox" /> <span>Gynaecology</span>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item col-12">
      <input type="checkbox" /> <span>Internal Medicine</span>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item col-12">
      <input type="checkbox" /> <span>Dermatology</span>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item col-12">
      <input type="checkbox" /> <span>Ophthalmology</span>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item col-12"><input type="checkbox" /> <span>Gyna</span></li>
    <li class="nav-item col-12">
      <input type="checkbox" /> <span>Orthopaedics</span>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item col-12">
      <input type="checkbox" /> <span>Otorhinolaryngology</span>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item col-12">
      <input type="checkbox" /> <span>Pharmacist</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I am trying to click on checkbox when the text near to the checkbox equal to specific text as clicking on orthopaedics when the variable is orthopaedics

i can find the checkbox and click on it without problem and i can print the text of each one but can't link both text and checkbox

```
html_list = browser.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/span/form/div[1]/div[3]/div/ul")
items = html_list.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME,"li")

for item in items:
    if item.text == "Paediatrics":
        item.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
for item in items:
    if item.text == "Paediatrics":
        checkbox = item.find_elements_by_class_name("input")[0]
        checkbox.click()
```

Comment: i already doing these sry i just copied old version of the code but still not working nothing happens

Comment: Maybe it's because it's clicking the list item and not the checkbox, try the code above. Try printing out values if it fails. Let me know what you come up with.

Comment: that's right it click on the text when I print it prints the texts correct without any problem

Comment: @AliAshour does the code work though?

Comment: everything works fine when I try to print the texts and everything works fine when I click on a certain check box by XPath but I can't link the checkbox with the text to make condition